# How to disable Google Maps double tap zooming?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

How to disable Google Maps SDK double tap zooming (but not pinch zooming) in iOS SDK?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

> For Swift 2.1

You can do this on your `GMSMapView` object,

```
mapView.settings.zoomGestures = false
```

Same goes for disabling tilt gesture, rotate gesture, scroll gestures,

```
mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
mapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
mapView.settings.scrollGestures = false
```

Read more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/controls#map_gestures

Unfortunately there is no way to disable double tap zoom while still keeping pinch zoom gestures. (I could be wrong, but I have went through their docs and haven't found a way to do so)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
  [googleMapView.settings setAllGesturesEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: he said that he wants to disable only double taps. this will disable all

Answer (score 0):

install your own tapgesturerecognizer and make it receive double taps. that way it won't be given to the google map.

Answer (score 0):

put this in controller

```
/// this gesture will disable zoom gesture temporarily
var tmpDisableZoom: UITapGestureRecognizer!
/// how long you want to lock
let lockDoubleTapTimeDelay = 0.3
/// finally unlock time
var unlockDoubleTapTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
override func viewDidLoad() {
    mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
    tmpDisableZoom = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeZoomGesturesTemporarily))
    tmpDisableZoom.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
}
@objc func removeZoomGesturesTemporarily(sender:UIGestureRecognizer){
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = false
    unlockDoubleTapTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + lockDoubleTapTimeDelay) { [weak self] in
        guard self != nil else {return}
        let timeNow = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        if timeNow - self!.unlockDoubleTapTime > self!.lockDoubleTapTimeDelay{
            self!.mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
        }
    }
}
```